# two tables mismatch columns values

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two tables Say Table1 (ID,Name,Description) and Table2 (ID,Name,Description).

I need to find out those records which does not exist of Table2 from Table1 and if record exist then it compares its Name and Description and display which ever column mismatch. ID is the field which is used for comparison.

eg

```
Table 1
( 1, Jon,Student) 

Table 2 
(1,Jon, Teacher)
```

so the query should return Description mismatch

Comment: Are you expecting someone to write the query for you, or do you have a question somewhere in there?

Comment: Have you tried any thing? you need help in SQL?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: Actually i am little confused is it possible by query or do i need to write Cursors in the SQL or do i need to create a custom program

Comment: You don't need to do either of those. You can find out by joining the tables and selecting an indicator based on the description columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with a SELECT

```
SELECT  TABLE1.ID,  CASE WHEN TABLE1.NAME <> TABLE2.NAME THEN 'NAME different' 
                         ELSE 'NAME equal'
                    END
                  , TABLE1.NAME, TABLE2.NAME
                  , CASE WHEN TABLE1.DESCRIPTION <> TABLE2.DESCRIPTION THEN 'DESCRIPTION different' 
                         ELSE 'DESCRIPTION equal'
                    END
                  , TABLE1.DESCRIPTION, TABLE2.DESCRIPTION
  FROM  TABLE1, TABLE2
 WHERE   TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
```

If you only want the joint rows which are different add to the were clause

```
AND (TABLE1.NAME <> TABLE2.NAME OR TABLE1.DESCRIPTION <> TABLE2.DESCRIPTION)
```

And if there might be ID's not in the other table you must use a left join

```
SELECT      TABLE1.ID,  
            CASE WHEN TABLE2.ID IS NULL THEN 'No corresponding row in TABLE2' END
            CASE WHEN TABLE1.NAME <> TABLE2.NAME THEN 'NAME different' ELSE 'NAME equal' END,           
            TABLE1.NAME, TABLE2.NAME
            CASE WHEN TABLE1.DESCRIPTION <> TABLE2.DESCRIPTION THEN 'DESCRIPTION different' ELSE 'DESCRIPTION equal' END,
            TABLE1.DESCRIPTION, TABLE2.DESCRIPTION
       FROM TABLE1
  LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT
t1.id,
CASE
WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN 'does not exist in table2'
WHEN t1.Name != t2.Name AND t1.Description = t2.Description THEN 'Name is different'
WHEN t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.Description != t2.Description THEN 'Description is different'
ELSE 'Both Name and Description differ'
END AS what_is_the_difference
FROM
table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```